# How to securely connect to PostgreSQL database, with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, security

I feel uncomfortable saving my password in a file:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG::Connection.open(host: 'server.example.com', password: 'hello_everyone')
```

Also, is there a way to determine or ensure that the transmission is encrypted? I am just worried about the implications of running my app locally, when it must connect to a remote database (I am worried about all the data, including the authentication credentials, being sent in the clear).

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding the password**:

I would recommend setting it in an ENV variable. Take a look at [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv). Basically, you are going to be able to do something like:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG::Connection.open(host: ENV['database_host'], password: ENV['database_password'])
```

The values that are loaded into ENV will be stored in a file (`.env`) which you should **not** commit.

**Regarding data encryption**

You should take a look at [SSH tunneling](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssh-tunnels.html) to connect to the remote DB.